# Serialize JSON as response to HTTP request

Tags: esp8266, web-server, json

I'd like my ESP8266 to provide some JSON endpoints. I want to use ArduinoJson for serialisation. While this works in general if I serialize into a String and return this String afterwards, I was wondering if there is really no way to do this without wasting so much memory. Shouldn't it be possible to do something like this? Any hints?

```
ESP8266WebServer server;
StaticJsonDocument<768> response;
response["night"] = _playback.isNight();
response["shuffle"] = _playback.isShuffle();
server.send_P(200, "application/json", NULL);
serializeJson(response, server.client());
```

(this gives the following error:)

```
no instance of overloaded function "serializeJson" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (ArduinoJson6141_0000010::StaticJsonDocument<768U>, WiFiServer::ClientType)
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of ArduinoJson? Did you try? Did it work? If not, what errors did you get?

Comment: Yes I did. Yes I tried. No it did not. I added the error message.

Comment: you can just build it as a string. imho, the big advantage of the json lib is parsing, not serializing.

Comment: Weird. `WiFiServer::ClientType` [is defined as `WiFiClient`](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.6.3/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/WiFiServer.h#L65), which [inherits from `Client`](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.6.3/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/src/WiFiClient.h#L45), which [inherits from `Stream`](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.6.3/cores/esp8266/Client.h#L26), which [inherits from `Print`](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/2.6.3/cores/esp8266/Stream.h#L38), which you should be able to serialize to. Could you try to serialize to `Serial`, just to see if it works?

Comment: That’s what I thought! I serialized into a char[] and it works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`serializeJson()`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/json/serializejson/) accepts a `Print&`, i.e, a reference to a class that implements the `Print` interface.

`WiFiClient` does implement the `Print` interface, but [`serializeJson()`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/json/serializejson/) cannot make a reference to it because `ESP8266WebServer::client()` returns a temporary. Indeed, C++ forbids references to temporary variables, only `const` reference to temporaries are allowed.

To fix this compilation error, you must extract a variable:

```cpp
WiFiClient client = server.client();
serializeJson(doc, client);
```

The way I see it, `ESP8266WebServer::client()` should return a `WiFiClient&` instead of a `WiFiClient`, just as `HTTPClient::getStream()` does. I opened [issue #7075](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/7075) about that.

Anyway, even it this fixes the compilation, I'm not sure it will work as you intend because `ESP8266WebServer` may not allow writing directly to the `WiFiClient`.